# How can I print a value returned by a generator function?

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I'm trying to print the third value returned by a generator function that generates odd numbers less than 10. However, I haven't been able to print any values at all. The most common answer to this question I've found has been the code below.

```
def get_odds():
    yield (n for n in range(10) if n % 2 != 0)
for n in get_odds():
    print(n)
```

This returns:

`<generator object get_odds.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001C88ABFC258>`

It should return `1`, then `3`, and so on. How do I return the value generated by a generator function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(n for n in range(10) if n % 2 != 0)` is a generator in its own right. It is what your print statement is picking up when you yield it. Here are a few ways to rewrite your code to behave as you want it to.

The trivial:

```
for n in (n for n in range(10) if n % 2 != 0): 
    print(n)
```

A generator function without an explicit yield:

```
def get_odds():
    return (n for n in range(10) if n % 2 != 0)
for n in get_odds():
    print(n)
```

A generator function with a yield:

```
def get_odds():
    for n in range(10): 
        if n % 2:
            yield n
for n in get_odds():
    print(n)
```

An overkilled fix for the code as posted:

```
def get_odds():
    yield (n for n in range(10) if n % 2 != 0)
for n in next(get_odds()):
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your way, your generator contain another generator

```
>>> def get_odds():
...     yield (n for n in range(10) if n % 2 != 0)


>>> odd = get_odds()
>>> odd
<generator object get_odds at 0x102270f10>
>>> n = next(odd)
>>> n
<generator object get_odds.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x102270eb8>
>>> next(n)
1
>>> next(n)
3
>>> next(n)
5
```

you should write code like this:

```
def get_odds():
    for n in range(10):
        if n % 2 != 0:
            yield n
```

Comment: Not a tuple… a generator because it has a `for` in it

Comment: yeah, it's a generator,  and it contain only another generator that you want

Comment: I mean that it is not a tuple. You should consider rewording your answer